# Send Soap Request in java with Authentication

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

I want to send a java soap req to a web service:

url: (https://webapplicaties.agro.nl/OpvragenPandEnergieLabel/EpbdOpvragenPandEnergieLabelService.asmx?WSDL)

This is the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <soapenv:Envelope 
   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
   xmlns:epb="http://schemas.ep- 
   online.nl/EpbdOpvragenPandEnergieLabelHeader" 
   xmlns:epb1="http://schemas.ep- 
   online.nl/EpbdOpvragenPandEnergieLabelRequest">
 <soapenv:Header>
  <epb:PandEnergieLabelHeader>
     <epb:username>username</epb:username>
     <epb:password>password</epb:password>
     <epb:versienr>4</epb:versienr>
  </epb:PandEnergieLabelHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <epb1:GetPandEnergieLabel>
    <epb1:Pand_postcode>postcode</epb1:Pand_postcode>
     <epb1:Pand_huisnummer>housnr</epb1:Pand_huisnummer>
     <epb1:Pand_huisnummer_toev>extra</epb1:Pand_huisnummer_toev>
    </epb1:GetPandEnergieLabel>
   </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

and the response should be like this.

Which steps should I take to have a such a response?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <PandEnergieLabel xmlns="http://schemas.ep-online.nl/EpbdExportTypes">
            <Pand_gebouwklasse>W</Pand_gebouwklasse>
            <Pand_is_op_basis_van_referentie_gebouw>false</Pand_is_op_basis_van_referentie_gebouw>
            <Pand_opnamedatum>29-04-2011</Pand_opnamedatum>
            <Pand_berekeningstype>EP</Pand_berekeningstype>
            <Pand_energieprestatieindex>1.21</Pand_energieprestatieindex>
            <Pand_energieklasse>B</Pand_energieklasse>
            <Pand_energielabel_is_prive>false</Pand_energielabel_is_prive>
            <Pand_forfaitaire>1.21</Pand_forfaitaire>
            <Meting_geldig_tot>29-04-2021</Meting_geldig_tot>
            <Pand_registratiedatum>29-04-2011</Pand_registratiedatum>
            <Pand_postcode>1072XC</Pand_postcode>
            <Pand_huisnummer>79</Pand_huisnummer>
            <Pand_huisnummer_toev>A</Pand_huisnummer_toev>
            <Pand_gebouwcode />
            <Pand_gebouwtype>Portiekwoning</Pand_gebouwtype>
            <Pand_gebouwsubtype>Tussenvloer</Pand_gebouwsubtype>
        </PandEnergieLabel>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How should I use Variables inside the request to ask for multiple addresses (postcode, housnr, ...)

Thanks

Comment: you are using Spring?

Comment: Does not matter i am just looking for result because it is urgent